# Want to split a string into 2 parts and holding each one in a different variable using c#

Tags: c#, textbox, split

I want to split a string that is "`12:00PM`".

Now I want `12:00` as one part and `PM` as another part.

And I want to give those two parts into two different textboxes.

In how many ways can I do that?

Comment: Is it always the time and will it show 08:00pm or 8:00pm?

Comment: [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split.aspx)? You have IntelliSense at your fingertips—use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String data = "12:00pm";
String time = data.substring(0, 5);
String ampm = data.substring(5, 2);
```

Tons of examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - I've only answered based upon the question.

Comment: However otherwise the answer would easily be: ampm = "pm"; time = "12:00";

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Split`:

```
var results = yourString.Split("p");
```

It returns an array. You can access the first result by using:

```
results[0];
```

And the second by:

```
results[1];
```

To assign the value to the TextBox, you can do:

```
TextBox1.Text = results[0];
TextBox2.Text = results[1];
```

Comment: Losing the the letter 'p'?

Comment: And how can i give 1st value to textbox1 and second value to textbox2?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - I've only answered based upon the question.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers yes, you are right i need a solution which can be applied for both am and pm. thanks

Comment: @Belogix, yes it will show 08:00pm it will always be like that

Comment: However otherwise the answer would easily be: ampm = "pm"; time = "12:00";

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string str = "12:00pm";
int timeIndex = str.Length - 2;
string time = str.Substring(0, timeIndex);  <--- 12:00
string ampm = str.Substring(timeIndex);     <--  am/pm
```

OR

```
string str = "9:00pm";
string time = new String(str.TakeWhile(c => c != 'p' && c != 'a').ToArray());
string ampm = str.Substring(str.Length - 2);
```

OR

```
string str = "9:00pm";
string time = str.Replace("am", "").Replace("pm", "");
string ampm = str.Substring(str.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `12:00pm` is actually coming from a `DateTime` you could use the built-in date formats for this e.g.

```
var timeStr = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm");
var amPm = dateTime.ToString("tt");
```

If not, then it's just a case of stripping away the last 2 characters from the string i.e.

```
var timeStr = "12:00pm";
var time = timeStr.Substring(0, timeStr.Length-2);
var amPm = timeStr.Substring(timeStr.Length-2);
```

Comment: @codingbiz yeah that second parameter wasn't required, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to always put am/pm in one box and time in another:

```
string rawText = "12:00pm";
txtTime.Text = rawText.Substring(rawText.Length - 2);
txtAmPm.Text = rawText.SubString(0, txtTime.Text.Length);
```

That would then also work for 8:00am etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ampm = date.substring(date.Length - 2, 2);
String time = date.substring(0, date.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "12:00pm";
string[] array = s.Split(new char[] { 'p', 'a' });
if (s.Contains("p"))
    array[1] = array[1].Replace("m", "pm");
else
    array[1] = array[1].Replace("m", "am");

TextBox1.Text = array[0];
TextBox2.Text = array[1];
```

This works both `pm` and `am`.

Comment: I've only answered based upon the question btw.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex with capture groups, think this should do it in .NET `^(?<firstGroup>^.*?)(?<secondGroup>(pm|PM|am|AM))`

And accessing it (very simplistic, assuming it has a single match only in the string)

```
expr.Matches(stringToSplit)[0].Groups["firstGroup"].Captures[0].Value
```

Bit of a round trip though.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to get the correct position of the am/pm string you could use [IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) string method, then the job to grab the right/left part of the string is easy with the two variations of [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

```
string test = "12:00pm";
int pos = test.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'p', 'm'});
string time = test.Substring(0, pos);
string ampm = test.Substring(pos);

textBox1.Text = time;
textBox2.Text = ampm;
```

Perhaps a check on the value of the variable pos `(pos != -1)` is needed if there is the possibility that this code will be called for a string without the am/pm specification

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `Take()` and `Skip()`:

```
var time = "12:00PM";

var hours = new string(time.Take(5).ToArray());
var amPm = new string(time.Skip(5).ToArray());
```